# cannot release memory after calling a macro in excel vba

Tags: python, excel, vba, memory-management

I've been looking around other questions here but could not find a solution to my topic.
I noticed that, each time I call a Macro in VBA inside Excel, which actually runs some python code via Microsoft Script Control, the memory used by the macro is not released, although I managed to set everything used inside the routine to Nothing (and eventually calling the garbage collector inside the python script).

Here's the code:

```vb
Sub save_rt()
    Dim lc As MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
    Set lc = New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
    lc.Language = "python"
    lc.Timeout = 50000 'in sec
    workingdir = Range("xmldir").Cells.Value
    lc.ExecuteStatement ("import pandas as pd")
    lc.ExecuteStatement ("import numpy as np")
    lc.ExecuteStatement ("import gc")

    myvalues = Range("icap_cf_values").Cells
    n_righe = UBound(myvalues)
    n_colonne = UBound(myvalues, 2)
    lc.ExecuteStatement ("myvalues = []")
    For i = 1 To n_righe
        For j = 1 To n_colonne
            If VarType(myvalues(i, j)) = vbString Then
                lc.ExecuteStatement ("myvalues.append('" + myvalues(i, j) + "')")
            Else
                lc.ExecuteStatement ("myvalues.append('" + Str(myvalues(i, j)) + "')")
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    lc.ExecuteStatement ("myvalues = np.array([item for item in myvalues])")
    lc.ExecuteStatement ("myvalues = myvalues.reshape(" + Str(n_righe) + "," +    Str(n_colonne) + ")")
    myindex = Range("icap_cf_mats").Cells
    lc.ExecuteStatement ("myindex = []")
    For Each d In myindex
        lc.ExecuteStatement ("myindex.append('" + d + "')")
    Next 
    mycolumns = Range("icap_cf_cols").Cells
    lc.ExecuteStatement ("mycolumns = []")
    For Each d In mycolumns
        lc.ExecuteStatement ("mycolumns.append('" + d + "')")
    Next
    lc.ExecuteStatement ("rt = pd.DataFrame(myvalues,index=myindex,columns=mycolumns)")

    A = lc.Eval("rt.to_csv('" + workingdir + "\\fwd_cfs.csv')")

    lc.ExecuteStatement ("del rt, myvalues, mycolumns")
    lc.ExecuteStatement ("gc.collect()")    
    Set myindex = Nothing
    Set mcolumns = Nothing
    Set myvalues = Nothing
    Set n_righe = Nothing
    Set n_colonne = Nothing
    Set A = Nothing
    Set workingdir = Nothing
    Set lc = Nothing

End Sub
```

I noticed that each time I call the Macro, it increases the memory used by Excel by 7mb and doesn't release it.
I don't know what else I'm missing here. Hope someone can help me out with this.
Thank yo